# Setting cursor to pointer over movieclip

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4, flash

I want to change cursor to pointer when I hover movieclip in the stage. 
I try this

```
MovieClip(this.myContainer.myStage.getChildAt(i)).buttonMode=true;
MovieClip(this.myContainer.myStage.getChildAt(i)).useHandCursor=true;
```

But it's doesn't help... Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: is there a reason you can't set that when it's first created?

Comment: Yes... I set interval and after 200 miliseconds mouse overing it starts higlighting and I want to change cursor to pointer when highlight starts ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution for it

```
[Embed(source='../assets/hand_cursor.png')]
private var _handIcon:Class;
```

And then I use

```
this.myContainer.cursorManager.setCursor(_handIcon,2,-3);
```

And it works fine)))

Answer (score 2):

```
MovieClip(myContainer.myStage.getChildByName("myChild"+i)).buttonMode=true;
```

Comment: Read my question again, I have already said that it doesn't work.

Comment: You have used `getChildAt(i)` but i have used `getChildByName`. you didn't told `getChildByName` method is not working.

Did u try this?

Comment: I don't think that there can be any difference... I can't use this, because my I don't set name to my movieclip and because I use getChildAt to do some other actions and they are working fine)))

Comment: I tried something like.. one MC(named as myCont) and within that 4 childes(named  as mychild1, mychild2 and so on). For this getChildAt(i) not worked... but getChildByName("myChild"+i) was worked well..  Give a try..

Comment: Y? Is u can't assign name while creating movieClips?